# Expo react-native bare workflow using Push notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Firstly i will be really appreciated for your helps.
I'am trying to implement expo push notification using expo-bare workflow. When i run app, it gives me error like this so i could not get token.
error `[TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_ExponentNotifications.default.getExponentPushTokenAsync')]`

Here is my code:

```js
import { Notifications } from "expo";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

export const getToken = async () => {
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      console.log("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
      return;
    }
    token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
  }
  else {
    console.log("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
  }
  return token;
};
```

Comment: Bare workflow uses expo-notifications package - https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-notifications

Comment: I followed this instruction that you commented sir. Maybe i may try your way you share code below and i will inform you back. Thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the expo notifications package:

`expo install expo-notifications` also don't forget to `cd` into the `ios` folder and run `pod install` to properly link the package.

Next, you need to change the way you import and use Notifications like:

`import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';`

Then to get expo token you do something like:

`Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({experienceId:'@your_username/your_app_slug'})`

which would resolve to a promise containing your expo token in an object format like:

`{"data": "ExponentPushToken[ID]", "type": "expo"}`

NB: Most method support in the Notifications from expo is different from the one in expo-notifications. You should check [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-notifications) for more details.

Comment: My issue is was around `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({experienceId:'@your_username/your_app_slug'})` . Double check the experienceId

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment some, I had a similar setup as yours when I was on Expo managed, but I ejected. According to [their docs](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-notifications), the bare workflow is a little different, and so mine is set up like this:

```
// at the top:

import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

// --------

// inside the code:

let settings = false

settings = Notifications.getPermissionsAsync()

if (!settings.granted) {
  settings = Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync()
}

if (settings.status === 1 || settings.status === 'granted') {
  const experienceId = '@proj/example' // (see docs on using expo credentials:manager)
  const token = Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({ experienceId })

  const resp = api.sendNotificationToken({ token: token.data })
}
```

Comment: Sir could you please explain how can i get the experienceId where is it ?

Comment: Now i got expo token properly but when i trying to send push notification using expo tool it says "InvalidCredentials: Unable to retrieve the FCM server key for the recipient's app. Make sure you have provided a server key as directed by the Expo FCM documentation." i upload my FCM credentials to expo i don.t know why i am getting this error.

Comment: for android you need to follow the guide to set up a Firebase messaging key, and upload it via the expo credentials manager

Comment: I uploaded my FCM key to the expo. Now i got expo token and then i sent notification via expo tool but i did not receive notification.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support daybreaker. The solution was i done is remove expo push notifications and instead of expo i decided to use react-native-firebase cloud messaging library. I follow react-native-firebase installition and everythink is working perfectly. Expo is killing me, in the future project i will never use expo :)